# A coin is tossed 5 times and each flip is either heads or tails. How many possible outcomes contain more heads than tails?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The question is: A coin is tossed 5 times and each flip is either heads or tails. How many possible outcomes contain more heads than tails?

So my reasoning is that it can be:

5 heads = c(5,5) = 5!/5!(5-5)! = 5!/5! = 1

4 heads = c(5,4) = 5!/4!(5-4)! = 5!/4!1! = 5!/4! = 5

3 heads = c(5,3) = 5!/3!(5-3)! = 5!/3!2! = 5*4/2! = 10

so in total 16 possible outcomes. does this seem right?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

There are $2^5=32$ equiprobable different outcomes. As $5$ is odd each outcome either has more heads or more tails. Due to symmetry both cases occur equally often. The answer therefore is $16$.